# Не открывается главная форма, winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

в одной форме я воздал кнопку и в коде на событие клик установил открытие главной формы, вот код:

```
   private void btnMain_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainForm main = new MainForm();
        this.Hide();
        main.Show();
    }
```

Это окно наз-ся DevForm, а я хочу по клику переходить в главное окно, но при нажатии мне открывается пустая форма, в чём проблема, пожалуйста помогите. Вот фото когда я нажимаю на свою кнопку, что происходит
[image: Через это окно я хочу перейти по кнопке в главную]

[image: Но вот что происходит]

Но вот что получается

Comment: Так вы не возвращаетесь к форме, а создаете новую. ООП, `new` создает новую копию объекта.

Comment: а как тогда вызвать?

Comment: ссылка на пример выше в синем блоке над вопросом